# How deal with VIF and condition numbers?

Tags: regression, variance-inflation-factor

I’m running multicollinearity checks on OLS regressions in stata (with 60 and 40 observations). The VIFs were not cause for concern (i.e., < 10) but the condition number in some cases was 300.
I dropped one control variable and this reduced the condition number to <20 but it also means I lose one of two controls.
I’m asking whether this approach is correct? If not, do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Is a condition number of 300 bad? What about 20? Hard to tell, it might be better to look at the standard errors of the coefficients to check if there is something weird going on.

Comment: The std. err. for the coefficient I dropped is .0625576 (compared to .5164869 and .2285494 for some of the others). What should I look out for in the std. errors? Thank you

Comment: The SE by itself is utterly without meaning!  (For instance, a standard error of 0.06 in units of tons per year would be huge compared to a slope estimate of one Kg per year, while a SE of 0.06 in units of microns per year would be negligible compared to a slope estimate of one meter per year.)  You need to compare it to the coefficient estimate itself.

Comment: In one regression (with 250 condition number), .1551387 (coefficient) and .0606531 (SE). In another regression (with 238 condition number): .0186247 (coefficient) and .1726348 (SE). Thank you.